# ADAL Python to Refresh PowerBI dataset

Tags: python, powerbi

I found a piece of code on Azure documentation that allows getting credentials without MFA. But I'm wondering if is possible to use it to connect to PowerBI API.

The piece of code that I'm using is:

```
import adal
import requests
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AADTokenCredentials

def authenticate_client_key():

    authority_host_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
    tenant = 'tenant'
    authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant
    resource_uri = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
    client_id = 'clientid'
    client_secret = 'client-secret'

    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_uri, api_version=None)
    mgmt_token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_uri, client_id, client_secret)
    credentials = AADTokenCredentials(mgmt_token, client_id)

    return credentials
```

source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/

According to the code written on PowerShell, the aim is to insert the access_token into the header of the following POST request

POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/me/datasets/{dataset_id}/refreshes

**Source:**https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/

I have tried to use the credentials into the POST request, but seems is not working.

I have tried

```
url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/me/datasets/datasetid/refreshes'
requests.post(url,data=mgmt_token)
```

Is it possible to merge this two codes?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pypowerbi package to refresh Power BI datasets or you can check how to do it yourself by inspecting the code. https://github.com/cmberryau/pypowerbi

```sh
pip install pypowerbi
```

```py
import adal
from pypowerbi.client import PowerBIClient

# you might need to change these, but i doubt it
authority_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
resource_url = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
api_url = 'https://api.powerbi.com'

# change these to your credentials
client_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
username = 'someone@somecompany.com'
password = 'averygoodpassword'

# first you need to authenticate using adal
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority=authority_url,
                                     validate_authority=True,
                                     api_version=None)

# get your authentication token
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(resource=resource_url,
                                                     client_id=client_id,
                                                     username=username,
                                                     password=password)

# create your powerbi api client
client = PowerBIClient(api_url, token)

# Refresh the desired dataset (dataset and group IDs can be taken from the browser URL)
client.datasets.refresh_dataset(dataset_id='data-set-id-goes-here',
                                notify_option='MailOnCompletion',
                                group_id='group-id-goes-here')
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use client_id and client_secret without using a username and password at all?

Answer (score 2):

Your code for acquiring an access token looks ok, but to use it with Power BI REST API, you must change `resource_uri` to be `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api`.

When making a request to Power BI REST API, you must add `Authorization` header with value `Bearer {accessToken}`, where `{accessToken}` is the token acquired. I can't write in python, but you should do something like this:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/me/datasets/datasetid/refreshes'
requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

(of course, you need to replace `datasetid` with actual value in `url`).

For example, here is how it can be done in C#:

```
string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";
string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
string powerBIApiUrl = $"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/refreshes";

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, new TokenCache());
var authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
var accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

var request = WebRequest.Create(powerBIApiUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken));
using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

Comment: It works great, the problem is that it generates a 401 status code error. Even if I change the resource URL, do you think is not aimed to PowerBI?

Comment: 401 means "unauthorized", I don't know. I use `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize` authority and it works. I added my (simplified) c# code in my answer. If you try to use this authority, it may work. Otherwise try to decode the access token in https://jwt.io and see the contents. It may give you some ideas why it is not authorized. Check do you get `Dataset.ReadWrite.All` permission in it.

Comment: @angelo do you have the working code for acessing power bi api?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov it seems like your code is not using client secret. How do you access to API? Is there any prompt asking for access?

Comment: `PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)` means that it will prompt for credentials if needed. For silent authentication, you need to pass the credentials to `AcquireTokenAsync`, e.g. `var uc = new UserPasswordCredential("user@example.com", "password"); authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, uc)`