# Is it possible to refresh an PowerBI Dataset with client id and client secret on python?

Tags: python, powerbi

I have tried to find code that allows to refresh PowerBI datasets with only having clientID and clientSecret.The account under my email uses MFA, so for security reasons I want to avoid using user and password because that would mean that I need to deactivate my MFA.

The code I have seen in Python and even in PowerShell doesn't have this option.

I'm currently using ADAL for connecting to *PowerBI API*.

I have seen in *GitHub* the documentation for ADAL and the different ways of creating the token for accessing the API and have found a function called 
*auth_context.acquire_token_with_authorization_code*. The question is, what CODE is and where I can find it? Or that is the MFA code?

Github reference:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/website_sample.py#L111-L119

I have stated my code here:
[ADAL Python to Refresh PowerBI dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762407/adal-python-to-refresh-powerbi-dataset)

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In my own research I found that, "No", you cannot do this with clientID and clientSecret which was given to you when registered the app as a Server Side. You must register it as a Native App in order to do this correctly.
Helpful resource:
https://pivotalbi.com/automate-your-power-bi-dataset-refresh-with-python/